# Python word length

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way that I can set only some variables.

```
l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8, l9, = (' ',)*9
word = input("Choose up to a 9 letter word: ")
wordlist = list(word)
wordl = len(word)
l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8, l9, = (wordlist)
```

More specifically is there a way that if someone enters a 6 letter word that it will only set up l6 and leave l7-l9 blank?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Split a word into characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should use a list. If `l` were a list (so you have `l[0], l[1], ..., l[9] = ...`), this does what you want:

```
for (index, letter) in enumerate(word):
  l[index] = letter
```

(I assume you have some reason to want to leave later variables unassigned. if you just want them blank a simpler string padding method is better)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do any of that. If you want to fill unused characters with a space, you can use `str.ljust` or string formatting.

```
>>> 'word'.ljust(9)
'word     '
>>> '{:<9}'.format('word')
'word     '
```

Answer (score 1):

I really don't understand what you are trying to do, but if you want to assign values to `l1`, `l2`... `l9` based on the suffix(number) where the suffix corresponds to the length word then here's the code:

```
>>> l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8, l9, = (' ',)*9
... word = input("Choose up to a 9 letter word: ")
... locals().update({'l'+str(len(w)): w for w in word.split() if len(w)<10})
... l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8, l9,
Choose up to a 9 letter word: idoKtknow waht you trying ti do ?
10: ('?', 'do', 'you', 'waht', ' ', 'trying', ' ', ' ', 'idoKtknow')
```

Comment: How would that work? couldn't you just split a list then for each char increment 1 var and print the length?

Comment: Based on what I understood,  OP wants to assign words to the variables suffixed by the word length. And the above works fine for the same!

Answer (score 0):

You can pad the input iterable with something like `None`, then slice the padded iterable to the expected length.

```
l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8, l9 = (list(word) + [None]*8)[:9]
```

No matter how short `word` is, the combined word/`None` list has at least 9 characters; the slice trims the extras.

However, more often you don't need separate variables for each letter; just store the list `l = list(word)` and use `l[i]` in place of each individual `l`-variable.